# How to calculate the chance of applying a bonus(i.e crit chance)?

Tags: c

Sorry if the question isn't clear, english is not my main language so i didn't knew how to compose it. My teacher gave an exercise to calculate who would win in a duel giving their health and attack. I wanted to expand on it a bit and added armor, critical chance and critical damage as extra stats, now I'm trying to figure out how to apply the chance of a critical in the damage. Here is where I've got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int HP;
    int damage;
    int armor;
    float crit_damage;
    float crit_chance;
} atributes;

//how to implement crit_chance?
//using a function?
//divide 100 for the crit_chance
//Ex: crit_chance = 25 ; 100/25 = 4
//generate a random number between 1 and 4
//if the number is 4 the crit_chance is sucessfull
//if not then the crit_chance fails
//aply then the result of the funcion to character[i].crit_damage

int main() {
    int i, rounds = 0;
    atributes character[2];

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("\tCharacter %d atributes\n", i+1);
        printf("    Damage = ");
        scanf("%d", &character[i].HP);
        printf("    HP = ");
        scanf("%d", &character[i].damage);
        printf("    Armor = ");
        scanf("%d", &character[i].armor);
        printf("    Crit Damage = ");
        scanf("%f", &character[i].crit_damage);
        printf("    Crit Chance = ");
        scanf("%f", &character[i].crit_chance);
        printf("\n");
    }

    while ((character[0].HP > 0) || (character[1].HP > 0)) {
        character[0].HP -= (character[1].damage * (character[1].crit_damage) - character[0].armor * 2);
        character[1].HP -= (character[0].damage * (character[0].crit_damage) - character[1].armor * 2);
        rounds++;
    };

    if (character[0].HP > character[1].HP) printf("\tCharacter 1 won after %d rounds!", rounds);
        else if (character[0].HP < character[1].HP) printf("\tCharacter 2 won after %d rounds!", rounds);
            else printf("\tThe duel ended in a tie after %d rounds", rounds);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: you should use the crit chance percentage to decide when it will occur. in example: roll a random number between 0 and 100, if it is less than your crit chance deal the crit damage. if not deal normal damage. I am sorry I am away cant code it for you but i can help out if you need more details when i get back to work

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem/question, but this may help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm
- I think that you **will** have to use this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following works:

```
int is_critical = (rand()%4==3);
```

`rand()` is a function provided by `stdlib.h` which returns a value inclusively between `0` and `RAND_MAX` (a constant defined in `stdlib.h`).

`rand()%4` gives you the remainder when this value is divided by 4: this will be a number 0, 1, 2, or 3.

Asking `rand()%4==3` asks if the result is equal to 3 (though you could just as well choose 0, 1, or 2). Since 3 represents 25% of the outcomes, this corresponds to what you want and `is_critical` is 1 if there's a hit.

A caveat, though, since `RAND_MAX` is probably not evenly divisible by 4 some of the modulus results have a *slightly* higher chance of occurring than others, so you would never want to generate random numbers this way for anything that really matters (science, finance, crypto, &c).

You can generalize this method as follows:

```
int is_critical = (rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)>0.75;
```

Since both `rand()` and `RAND_MAX` give integers and `RAND_MAX` is larger than `rand()`, dividing them gives 0. So we convert `RAND_MAX` to float. The result is a "uniformly" distributed number in the range 0-1. This is greater than 0.75 with 25% chance, which is what you want.

Comment: how do i make the chance change depending on the character, like if `character[0].crit_chance` receives 35 and `character[1].crit_chance` receives 50